# Unable to get Firestore map-array workaround working

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to query firestore by specifying an array elements. Waiting for some more sophisticated queries types, I'm following [this official guide](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/arrays).

Because I'm not able to use this technique in my case, I tried to simulate the example on the firestore guide. So I have:
[image]

but querying for:

```
const db = firebase.firestore();
let ref = db.collection('events')
            .where('categories.cats', '==', true)

return ref.get();
```

And also in this case I'm always getting a querySnapshot of size 0.

Where I'm wrong here?

Comment: is `Constants.FIRESTORE_EVENTS='events'`? perhaps the constant is set wrong.

Comment: Also check your security rules

Comment: @asosnovsky yes. This code:

`const db = firebase.firestore();
        let ref = db.collection(Constants.FIRESTORE_EVENTS)
                    .where("owner_uid", "==", uid)
                    .where("state", "==", Constants.FIRESTORE_EVENTS_STATE_FULL)
                    .orderBy(Constants.FIRESTORE_TIMESTAMP_CREATION, 'desc')
        return ref.get();`

is working correctly.